# URL amigable en php

Tags: php, pretty-urls, reescritura-url

necesito una ayuda con este problema, tengo el siguiente código

```
<?php
include 'modules/head.php';
/**Contenido de pagina */
$rutas = array();

if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){
    $rutas = explode("/",$_GET["ruta"]);
    $rutaCategoria = CategoriaController::CtrlCategorias($rutas[0]);
    if($rutas[0]==$rutaCategoria){
        echo 'pagina categoria';
    }else{
        include 'modules/404page.php';
        echo $rutaCategoria;
    }
}
if (isset($_GET["ruta"])==false) {
    include 'modules/inicio.php';
}

/**Fin de contenido de pagina */

include 'modules/footer.php';
?>
```

donde $rutas solo toma el primer parámetro para buscarlo en una lista blanca de categorías que viene de un controlador que lo trae de una base de datos.

podría usar otra condicional para el detalle de cada producto pero me quedaría en el primer parámetro, como podría conservar el primer parámetro y tomar el segundo para el detalle del producto de tal manera que al ingresar a un producto la url quede así:

> dominio.com/categoria/producto

obviamente cada producto en la base de datos tiene asignado una categoría.

mi .htaccess tiene esta configuración:

```
# impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio

Options All -Indexes

# url amigables

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu htaccess recoges dos variables en lugar de una

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1&prod=$2
```

Y procesas la segunda variable para obtener el producto.